# Why my custom listview is not showing anything?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am making a list view to show all the upcoming contests in codeforces. So I have made a `CodeforcesContest` object and a fragment which contains a `ListView`. I want all the information about a contest to be in a row of the ListView. Contest informations are contest name, contest time, and another string to hold the site name, which is always "Codeforces". Here's what I have so far. I am pretty new with Java and android. I have searched and found ways to implement custom listview with custom class. However, my listview is not showing anything. I am using android studio 3.0

**CodeforcesContest.java**

```
package com.example.redwanul.cptracker;

/**
 * Created by redwanul on 12/1/17.
 */

public class CodeforcesContest {
    private String name;
    private String time;

    public CodeforcesContest(String name, String time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setTime(String time) { this.time = time; }
}
```

Custom layout for a single row.

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/contest_name"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/contest_site"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/date_time"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Fragment class for showing the ListView.

**FragmentUpcomingContest.java**

```
package com.example.redwanul.cptracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentUpcomingContest.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentUpcomingContest#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentUpcomingContest extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentUpcomingContest() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentUpcomingContest.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentUpcomingContest newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentUpcomingContest fragment = new FragmentUpcomingContest();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList <CodeforcesContest> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        CodeforcesContest[] contests;
        View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_upcoming_contest,container,false);

        ListView listView = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new GetCodeforcesContestList().execute().get();
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String _name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String _phase = jsonObject.getString("phase");
                String _time = jsonObject.getString("startTimeSeconds");
                Log.d("Debug: name",_name);
                Log.d("Debug: phase",_phase);
                Log.d("Debug: Time",_time);
                if(_phase.equals(new String("BEFORE"))){
                    arrayList.add(new CodeforcesContest(_name,_time));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        contests = new CodeforcesContest[arrayList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
            contests[i] = arrayList.get(i);
        }
        Log.d("Array Length: ", new Integer(arrayList.size()).toString());
        ContestAdapter mAdapter = new ContestAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.row,contests);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_upcoming_contest, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

The fragment layout.
**fragment_fragment_upcoming_contest**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.redwanul.cptracker.FragmentUpcomingContest">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView">

    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

My custom adapter for showing list.
**ContestAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.redwanul.cptracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by redwanul on 12/1/17.
 */

public class ContestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CodeforcesContest> {
    Context context;
    int layourResourceId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    CodeforcesContest[] data = null;

    public ContestAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CodeforcesContest[] data){
        super(context,layoutResourceId,data);
        this.layourResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        int ll = data.length;
        Log.d("Constructor",new Integer(data.length).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if(vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
        CodeforcesContest contest = data[position];
        Log.d("In Adapter",contest.getName());
        TextView contestName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.contest_name);
        TextView contestSite = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.contest_site);
        TextView timeDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date_time);

        Date date = new Date(Integer.parseInt(contest.getTime()) * 1000);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/D/YYYY");
        String dateString = formatter.format(date);

        contestName.setText(contest.getName());
        contestSite.setText("Codeforces");
        timeDate.setText(dateString);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: no. build did not show any error.

Comment: `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_upcoming_contest, container, false);` - You're not returning the `View` you inflated and setup at the beginning of `onCreateView()`. You need to `return myLayout;` there.

Comment: where is `GetCodeforcesContestList()`? is that an AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes @AswinPAshok that is an AsyncTask which is returning a JSONArray

Comment: I think, the problem is asynctask may take some time to load data. So `JSONArray jsonArray = new GetCodeforcesContestList().execute().get();` here you are getting an empty JSONArray. Thus the empty ListView. Try logging `jsonArray`. And take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16007765/7557205)

Comment: why dont you use RecyclerView ?

Comment: @AswinPAshok As far as I learned, if I call get() on the AsyncTask, the code waits for the AsyncTask to return object.

Comment: @RohitSingh I have not learned to use RecyclerView yet. Though my friend mentioned it to me several times.

Comment: Have you tried logging data?

Comment: @AswinPAshok Yes. It shows correct data.

Comment: please start using RecyclerView. It is more efficient in terms of memory usage. It has support for Animation too. You can change layout from linear to grid in just one line of code and it is just the tip of iceberg, you wouldnt regret

Comment: Please stop telling users to switch to `RecyclerView`, as though it's the panacea for all their `ListView` issues. If they can't get the data to show in a `ListView`, using a `RecyclerView` instead is _not_ going to solve anything.

Comment: The question had +1 a while ago, why downvote it?

Comment: you are right @MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - First change your **row.XML** height to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="9">
```

> - You returning wrong layout your should return  `myLayout`       instead of `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_upcoming_contest,`

**use this**

```
return myLayout;
```

**instead of this**

`return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_upcoming_contest,` container, false);

Comment: I have changed the code. The solution you provided seems ok to me. However, it is taking time to run the emulator. I will let u know if it fixed the problem, once the run is complete

Comment: It solve the problem. Now I am having problems showing the date. It is showing wrong date/time.

Comment: There was also an error with `inflater`. It was throwing null pointer exception

Comment: Null Pointer Exception is fixed.

Comment: @RedwanulHaqueSourave happy to help you enjoy codding