# Perform Async task of another activity (other than main activity) in Splash screen

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have a main activity [**Activity A** (displayed when the app is opened)] which consists a button( **Button 1**)

When button 1 is clicked , it opens up a new activity(**Activity B**) . Activity B consists of a listview which is loaded using Async task

Now i want to add a splash screen to my app so that the Async task performed in **Activity B** is done via Async task of the splash screen and when the user clicks on **Button 1**  , **Activity B** is displayed with the listview already loaded

Is this possible?

I know how to set the splash screen and use Async task in it

My code

**onclicklistener of button 1 of activity A**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
          public void onClick(View v){

            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);

           startActivity(i);
          )

});
```

**Async task of Activity B to load listview**

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityB.this);
        mProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait loading ....");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //my background process to load listview
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    istview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activityb_layoutListView);


        adapter = new MyAdapter(ActivityB.this, delist)


        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


 }
  }
```

**my doinbackground()**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        delist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "terActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");

            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {
                Delist map = new Delist();

                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));


                delist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You should load the data then pass it to your next activity using extras in the `Intent` you use to start it.

Comment: @Anyonymous2324 ya even i had that idea but how do you pass loaded data via intent, thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you a different way:

You can put the `SplashScreen` in your **ActivityB** layout file. You just put an image, or a gif or whatever you prefer and you place it in the front of the screen, always visible.

When your async task finishes, you simply call a `mySplashImage.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, and the trick is done.

Let me know if you hardly want a different splashscreenActivity or if this way is ok for you :)

**EDIT:**

Since you want to load your datas on application's start and pass them to next activities you have two ways:

**1- using parcelable**:

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents). They ask pretty the same thing and they explain how to use parcelable in objects. You just have to make your object implements `Parcelable` ([here is the official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)). then you can pass it using

> Intent i = new Intent();
>
> i.putExtra("name_of_extra", myParcelableObject);

And from the 2nd Activity

> getIntent().[getParcelableExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

**2- using string**

This is more a "workaround", but if you don't wanna to make your object implement parcelable, you can serialize it into a string, pass it using the `putExtra`, retrieving it using `getStringExtra()` and then deserialize it.

I hardly reccomend the `Parcelable` way because it has been created for this reason, but I gave you both ways so you can chose :)

**EDIT 2**

If you want to use in your activity the datas loaded in the `doInBackground()`, you need to pass them as a result to the `onPostExecute` method.

[here is the official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) of `AsyncTask` in case you need it, anyway the 3rd parameter type of the asynctask method you created, is the return type of your `doInBackground` method. now you used `void, void, void` and it means that noone of your asyncTask's methods will return nothing.

[here is an easy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273989/how-do-i-retrieve-the-data-from-asynctasks-doinbackground) on how to use it:
I try to edit your to return something :)

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<CodeList>> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();


    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityB.this);
    mProgressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Set progressdialog message
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait loading ....");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Show progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.show();

}


@Override
protected ArrayList<CodeList> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //my background process to load listview
    ArrayList<CodeList> delist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
    try {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
            "terActivity");
        // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
        // by ascending
        query.orderByAscending("_created_at");

        ob = query.find();
        for (ParseObject inter : ob) {
            Delist map = new Delist();

            map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));


            delist.add(map);
        }
        return delist;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CodeList> result) {
    //istview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activityb_layoutListView);
    //adapter = new MyAdapter(ActivityB.this)
    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    //listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    //here you use them
    //result are your objects returned from doInBackground.
    //now you can work with them as if you are in the onCreate
    If(result == null) { return; } 
    Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)result);
    intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

And in the new Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
ArrayList<CodeList> object = (ArrayList<CodeList>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

the problem of asyncTask is that the `doInBackground` works, as it says, in background. Couse of this you can't use the object in this method in your activity, neither you can start activities or other stuffs like this.

In `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`, you can do everything because they are invoked in the UI thread.

So now you have to start the next activity in onPostExecute with the params you got and the work is done :)

For any question i'm here

**EDIT 3**

I updated the code with your doInBackground. Since you got an ArrayList of items you should use [as they mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601883/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-from-one-to-another-activity-using-intent-in-an/13616719) the [serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) attribute on the object you want.

I wrote the code by hand here so it might need some adjustment but it should work :)

Comment: The process you said is same as i perform Async task and show progressdialog in Activity Bbut instead of progress dialog you suggested a splash screen for Activity B,,,But i want the splash screen as the app opens,thnx

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley i understood what you said but have a doubt regarging passing of loaded data means...?

Comment: @user5894647 sorry, my english is not really perfect at all. I mean passing datas which has been loaded/retrieved before (in this case you want to load datas when app starts and pass them to the next activity)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley no bro there is no problem with your engl7sh, its good and i get your point easily but how to pass loaded data that is happening in doinbackground()  of Activvity B

Comment: @user5894647 ok got it sorry, I will add this part :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley thnx very much

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley that is a relief now,, thnx for being patient and answering all my questions. Thank you very much. I will try it and letyou know if there is any problem

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley bro read the docs and the link you gave but confused about what to return in doinbackgroung() in my case....posted my doinbackgroung() method, please have a look

Comment: Which are the datas you need to pass to the next activity?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley the delist.add(map)

Comment: @user5894647 Edited :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley so spontaneous, 4hank you,, will try and let you know

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley its giving error at    ArrayList<CodeList> in onpostexecute,,,unknown variable or field ArrayKist, CodeList

Comment: @user5894647 edited again, i took probably the wrong code in copy-paste

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley but you did not return anything in doinbackgroung()

Comment: @user5894647 I'm with phone at the moment sorry, I added it now. You should add a return null after the catch and a null-check in the post execute :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley no problem but your answer did not get updated

Comment: @user5894647 check now ;)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley but i defined ddelist as a List variable not Arraylistt ,, like this    List<CodeList> delist

Comment: @user5894647 you can change the signature, into arraylist, they are technically the same.. Or you have to change arraylist type in the return into list

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley ok, thanks very much,,,,,a very big hug

Comment: @user5894647 no problems :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley no problems,working great. Thanks again